# Django- update a DateField model entry to be a string as a default

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a function in my Django model: `def add_default_date` This function, if called from the view, checks to see if `publish_date` is `None` and if it is, I'd like to change `publish_date` to be text: `"Date Needed"`. However right now when I do this I get an error: `"'Date Needed' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."`. It appear that I'm trying to assign a string to a `DateField` but it's not working. Is there anyway to do this?

*Models.py:*

```
class Byte(models.Model):
"""Model for databyte content."""

   publish_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


   def add_default_date(self):
       if self.publish_date is None:
           self.publish_date = "Date Needed"
```

*Views.py:*

```
bytes = Byte.objects.order_by(
        F('publish_date').desc(nulls_last=True)
    )

for b in bytes:
    Byte.add_default_date(b)
    b.save()
```

Comment: Maybe this could help you (convert string string to datetime) https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

Comment: why would you think of  storing in database something like following string, DateField is converted to proper database data type to store dates and it is not suitable to store strings anyway. You can always change representation in your view/serializer

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to not use a date field at all. Use a character field and when creating/saving model objects convert date to string. But, you won't be able to use Django's built-in sorting and filtering mechanisms.

A sketchy solution would be to use a very old date as a default. Then, in your function, hard code that date to be ignored in whatever process you're doing.

Lastly, you could keep it as a null date and in your templating use the {$ empty %} tag to signal what to show if a date is null. You could show 'Date Needed' on the html page, it would just be stored as null.